# How can I add multiple checkboxes to jScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jcheckbox

I have a Java connection with MySQL database. I inserted 30 variable to a MySQL table. I would like to create a graphical interface with Jframe where I can select the variables from the table using a checkbox.

I plan to do something similar as [Java Swing Group of checkbox multiple selection handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241488/java-swing-group-of-checkbox-multiple-selection-handler)

But I do not know how I can use it with NetBeans? I tried to add a newJFrame where I add a jScrollPane and I wanted to add multiple jCheckBoxes but I can add only one to jScrollPane.

Could someone let me know how I should add a group of checkboxes to jScrollPane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a JPanel to your JScrollPane, then add checkboxes to that JPanel.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
panel.add(checkbox1);
panel.add(checkbox2);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```